# Posting data to given URL using Bootstrap Wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to display a Wizard as shown in this [example](http://www.panopta.com/static/bootstrap-wizard-plugin/demo/demo.html). When i click on the Submit button the data is not posted to the given URL `/wizard_submit`. Help.

Note: For the full code please visit the given example.

```
 <div class="wizard" id="wizard-demo">
        <div class="wizard-card" data-onValidated="setServerName" data-cardname="name">
                <h1>First</h1>
<div class="control-group">
                    <input id ="name" type="text"
                     />
                </div>
        </div>
            <div class="wizard-card" data-onload="" data-cardname="location">
                <h3>LAST</h3>
    <div class="wizard-input-section">

                <select data-placeholder="Monitor nodes" style="width:350px;" class="chzn-select">
                    <option value=""></option>
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>

                </select>

            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="wizard-success">
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                Success!!!!
                </div>

                <a class="btn im-done">Close</a>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

                $.fn.wizard.logging = true;

                var wizard = $("#wizard-demo").wizard({
                    showCancel : true
                });
                wizard.on("submit", function(wizard) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "/wizard_submit",
                        type : "POST",
                        data : wizard.serialize(),
                        success : function() {
                            wizard.submitSuccess();

                            wizard.hideButtons();
                            wizard.updateProgressBar(0);
                        },
                        error : function() {
                            wizard.submitError();
                            wizard.hideButtons();
                        }
                    });
                });

                $(".chzn-select").chosen();

                wizard.el.find(".wizard-ns-select").change(function() {
                    wizard.el.find(".wizard-ns-detail").show();
                });

                wizard.el.find(".create-server-service-list").change(function() {
                    var noOption = $(this).find("option:selected").length == 0;
                    wizard.getCard(this).toggleAlert(null, noOption);
                });

                wizard.on("submit", function(wizard) {
                    var submit = {
                        "hostnamed" : $("#new-server-fqdn").val()
                    };

                    setTimeout(function() {
                        wizard.trigger("success");
                        wizard.hideButtons();
                        wizard._submitting = false;
                        wizard.showSubmitCard("success");
                        wizard.updateProgressBar(0);
                    }, 2000);
                });

                wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .im-done").click(function() {
                    wizard.reset().close();
                });

                wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .create-another-server").click(function() {
                    wizard.reset();
                });

                $(".wizard-group-list").click(function() {
                    alert("Disabled for demo.");
                });

                $("#open-wizard").click(function() {
                    wizard.show();
                });

                wizard.show();
            });
```

Comment: You have got an error for '_updateProgressBar'. That might be the issue.

Comment: How should i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
 var submit = {
                    "hostnamed" : $("#new-server-fqdn").val()
                };
```

and it should work (I had the same issue and removing this line worked.)

That line is unnecessary anyway, it looks like you've got the same code there as in the example and I'm guessing if you don't have an element with that Id it is causing an unrelated error.